# Magento different onepage checkout first step (2 variants)

Tags: onepage-checkout

we noticed the strangest thing. Sometimes it seems like Magento 'forgets' the checkout as guest option ... (that I am sure of that is active, because it always is)

However, sometimes we only see 1 option (instead of 2) : the only button available is create an account

Is there something logical that I am missing?

[image]

And the strange thing is that the setting is enable guest checkout = yes

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto adminpanel then.

```
system > configuration > checkout
```

In `Checkout options`

> **Enable**  Allow Guest Enable